# Why doesn't this code generate a constraint error or print a positive number?

Tags: ada

I would expect this code to either generate a constraint error or print a positive number. Why does this code do neither?

```pascal
with Ada.Text_IO;
use  Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Overflow is
   procedure P (I : Positive) is
      X : Integer := Integer'Last;
   begin
      X := (X + I) / 2;
      Put_Line (Integer'Image (X) & " should be positive");
   end;
begin
   P(10);
end;
```

Comment: What compiler/compiler version/compilation options? What does the code do?

Comment: gnat 6.3.0 (Debian Stretch) : `raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : overflow.adb:8 overflow check failed` (with default flags)

Comment: GCC 4.9.1 doesn’t raise CE by default; later versions do.

Comment: Where did this code come from? (it was already on my machine! from May 2016!!)

Comment: Ah! it was on Software Engineering - [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/324771) - but in lower-case!

Comment: If the question has already been asked elsewhere a year ago, I feel like this is a computer language troll topic or a training/homework trap ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because your compiler isn't configured to work as a proper Ada compiler.  Specifically, older versions of GNAT require a flags to work as a proper Ada compiler.  According to my notes, the flags are:

```
-fstack-check -gnata -gnato
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Using gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 and compiling with these options gives me the constraint error (see below) I was looking for:

gnatmake -fstack-check -gnata -gnato overflow.adb

./overflow
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : overflow.adb:8 overflow check failed

Comment: Interesting! 5.2 (on macOS) doesn’t need `-gnato` to raise CE.

Comment: With more recent versions of GNAT, you can control more specifically how intermediate results are calculated. -gnato1 calculates them using the base type of the integer subtype (same as -gnato for the example). -gnato2 uses the largest machine integer type; in the example, that would be equivalent to Long_Long_Integer, probably 64 bits, and this specific result would be mathematically correct. Some other expressions could still raise Constraint_Error, though. -gnat3 uses an unbounded integer type (big nums) for intermediate calculations, always ensuring mathematically correct results.